# What is your opinion on using MVCExtensions with Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, autofac, mvcextensions

I would like to know your opinion on using MVCExtensions with Autofac..

I am using [MVC Extensions](https://github.com/MvcExtensions/Core/wiki/) with `Autofac` in my `MVC 3 web app`.  I'm just not getting it why these extensions were created?  I can't really say that it is makng my life easier.  Everything that I did with Autofac in my global.asax.cs file I can do with the MVC extensions.  I can register routes, controllers, my services and repositories, etc with just Autofac.

Any opinions why using these MVC extensions is maybe a better way to go?

I need to capture my errors in `Application_Error`.  How do I get an instance of my registered logger?  If I need to resolve dependencies some where else in my app how would I do this?  This is how I register my logger:

```
builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>();
```

I can instantiate my logger but would rather like to use the registered logger.

Is there a tag for these extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access your logger through the DependencyResolver:

```
var logger = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILogger>();
```